# jQuery Plugin fancybox2 - version and deprecation

Tags: jquery, fancybox-2

I was looking to upgrade my fancybox v1.3.4 to the newer model - fancybox2. I have two questions that I was hoping someone may be able to give insight on. First, the github shows that they are using jQuery v1.7.x for their library so have they removed all deprecated functions to be compatible with the newest jQuery 1.x library?

The second question is will this plugin work as a plug and play, or will there be significant changes required to upgrade? I'm coming into a project and was hoping if any developers that use fancybox have decided to attempt to migrate to the newer version. I would attempt this, but it requires a license for business applications.

Any insight into either point is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having built at least ten sites with either version, I can give you this answers:

For the first question I can only give a vague answer, as I can just assume the 1.7.x dependency will have its reason. Most likely it has to do with ".on()/.off()" over ".live()".

2nd Question: I found the migration quite easy (some options/functions were renamed for the better), but it is a little more than simple lib replacement. The upgrade definitly pays off, especially with the multi-domain license offered, but that's just my opinion.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! I've been migrating .live() to .on() within my own views and the functionality appears to be the same. Am I correct in assuming I could go into the .js file for fancybox and manually flip the .live()'s over as long as I use the correct naming conventions for the event? 1.3.4 actually references .browser, so I am mostly concerned with that dependency over any function names.